# Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am struggling a lot to fix this issue. Can any one please help me to get through this. Please let me know where am I going wrong in my where clause in the query statement. I want to read values from all the columns and then give those to display.

Here is my query code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SQLiteDatabase db;
SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
Button btnlogin, btnsigup;
EditText loguname, logpass;
Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
    btnsigup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnpass);
    loguname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loguname);
    logpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.logpass);
    openHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    db = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String username =loguname.getText().toString();
            String pass =logpass.getText().toString();
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT *FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COL_2 + "='?' AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_4 + "='?' ", new String[]{username, pass});
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    btnsigup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Try to remove the single quotes around the question marks: `=?` instead of  `='?'`

Answer (score 0):

You forget to put space in between `SELECT * FROM` and as mention by [OH GOD SPIDERS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6073886/oh-god-spiders) remove single quotes around the question marks: `=?` instead of `='?'`

Try this code

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COL_2 + "=? AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_4 + "=? ";
cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{username, pass});
```

Comment: @arnabdas i made some changes try this now